# Using AJAX form submit to submit and retrieve data from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Basically, I'm trying to make it so that when a post is submitted to my site, it sends the post using AJAX so that they don't change page, and then if the AJAX post is successful, retrieve all the posts for said user from MySQL and write them onto the page.

My problem is that the browsers (Chrome, IE) are completely ignoring the AJAX request.

My form:

```
<div id="updatestatus">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="ps">
                        <textarea name="status" id="status"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" id="poststatus" name="poststatus" value="Share" />
                    </form>
                </div>
```

My AJAX request:

```
$(function() {  
$("#poststatus").click(function() {  
    var status = $("textarea#status").val();  

    if (status == "") {  
    return false;  
    }

    var uid = $("input#uid").val();  
    var dataString = 'status='+ status + '&uid=' + uid;  

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "updatestatus.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {  
            $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'ajax/query.php',         
                data: "uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>",        
                dataType: 'json',                
                success: function(data) {
                    var status = data[0];              
                    var sid = data[1];          
                    $('#mainprofile').html("<div id='statuses'><p>"+status+"</p></div>);
                    return false;  
                }  
            });  
        return false;  
        });  
    });
});
});
```

My ajax/query.php request

```
<?php 

  //connect stuff

    $uid = strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid'])))));

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mingle_status WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help - Joe

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo when pasting your code here but you have a missed `"` here `"status+"</p></div>);`

Comment: That was a typo thanks, I was hoping it was going to be something silly like that to fix it, unfortunately it didn't :/

Comment: When you say "completely ignores" could you add some breakpoints to determine how far said browsers get? And what about other browsers, do they make it work fine?

Comment: Added in some alerts at each stage, not one came up...

Comment: have you tried something like Firebug to see if there happens anything at all?

Comment: You didn't close the quote `html("<div id='statuses'><p>"+status+"</p></div>);`. Did you check the browser console if there were errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of JS code

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "updatestatus.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'ajax/query.php',         
            data: "uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>",        
            dataType: 'json',                
            success: function(data) {
                var status = data[0];              
                var sid = data[1];          
                $('#mainprofile').html("<div id='statuses'><p>"+status+"</p></div>);
                return false;  
            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    });  
});
```

You need to remove the ending bracket after the curly brace which follows the last return false, such as...

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "updatestatus.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {  
            $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'ajax/query.php',         
                data: "uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>",        
                dataType: 'json',                
                success: function(data) {
                    var status = data[0];              
                    var sid = data[1];          
                    $('#mainprofile').html("<div id='statuses'><p>"+status+"</p></div>");
                    return false;  
                }  
            });  
        return false;  
        };  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

$(function() {  
$("#poststatus").click(function() { 
    var status = $.trim($("#status").val());  

    if (status == "") {  
    return false;  
    }

    var uid = $("#uid").val();  
    var dataString = 'status='+ status + '&uid=' + uid;  

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "updatestatus.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {  
            $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'ajax/query.php',         
                data: "uid="+<?php echo $uid; ?>,      
                dataType: 'json',                
                success: function(data) {
                    var status = data[0];              
                    var sid = data[1];          
                    $('#mainprofile').html("<div id='statuses'><p>"+status+"</p></div>);
                    return false;  
                }  
            });  
        return false;  
        }  
    });
});
});
```